# Write the differential equation of yearly growth

Tags: calculus

I'm given that one microbe ($p_0=1$) starts to reproduce and the culture's population increases by $100 \%$ each second. How do we write the equation of $\frac{dp}{dt}$?

I initially thought I could say $\frac{dp}{dt}=p$, but solving won't give $p=2^{t}$.

If someone can explain this for me I'd really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the differential equation: $\frac{dp}{dt}=kp$

with boundary conditions $p=1$ at $t=0$ and $p=2$ at $t=1$.

Although you will end up with something like $p=Ae^{kt}$, you can find $A$ and $k$ by using your two boundary conditions. A little manipulation will let you turn this into the desired answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but do you mean $p=Ae^{kt}$ ?

Comment: I do! Fixed it now. Just the difference between Ae^kt and Ae^{kt}.

Comment: i solved it and got $2^t$. I guess I was mistakenly assuming that $\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$. thank you !